# Instrumentation tests crashing after Android Studio 3.5 and Gradle update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-instrumentation

After updating Android Studio to 3.5 version, which also updates Gradle version to 5.4.1. My instrumentation tests crash with a very strange error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/LazyThreadSafetyMode`

I have double-checked that all the Standard libraries along with Android libraries are up to date. Not sure what is causing the issue but both the app and unit tests run fine.

Here's my `app/build.gradle` file (omitting some unnecessary details since the file is too long):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.1'

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            manifestPlaceholders = [analytics_deactivated: "true", crashlytics_activated: "false"]
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), "$project.rootDir/tools/rules-proguard-debug.pro"
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/main.kotlin_module'
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        fatal 'StopShip'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    testOptions {
        // execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
        animationsDisabled true

        unitTests {
            all {
                // configure the test JVM arguments
                jvmArgs '-noverify'
                includeAndroidResources = true
                returnDefaultValues = true
            }
        }
    }
    testOptions.unitTests.all {
        testLogging {
            events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'standardOut', 'standardError'
            outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
            showStandardStreams = true
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

kapt {
    useBuildCache = true
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    flatDir { dirs 'libs-aar' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Google Support Library.
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"

    // AAC
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'

    // MDC
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'

    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$KOTLIN_VER"

    /** Testing **/

    // Android Testing Support Library
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0'
    androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0-alpha02'

    // Espresso
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and here's my project's `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    ext.detekt_version = '1.0.0-RC14'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$KOTLIN_VER"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.30.0'
        classpath 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android-gradle-plugin:4.5.2'
        classpath 'org.jlleitschuh.gradle:ktlint-gradle:6.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    apply plugin: "org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint"
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```